# Java StringTokenizer odd behavior

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I'm trying to extract only lowercase alphanumerical characters from a document with this:

```
String delim = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

StringTokenizer strtok = new StringTokenizer(str, delim, true);

String newstr = "";

while (strtok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    newstr = newstr + strtok.nextToken();
}

return newstr;
```

Note that the document is already lowercase only. But for some reason all of the punctuation characters are still being returned along with parethesis and /'s, etc.

I thought using the true boolean in the creation of the tokenizer would count delimiters as tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delim argument is a delimiter.  You're basically asking for each token to be "whatever is between lower case letters".  Then the 'true' argument says "give me those letters on the edges too".  Were you looking for `replaceAll("[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789]","")`?